# Refresh table data every 5 seconds with ajax based on toggle button status

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am creating a web page using Django and Ajax. I want to refresh my page every 5 seconds depending on the status of a bootstrap toggle switch.
i.e.

- On - Auto refresh table data every 5 seconds
- Off - Do not refresh

jQuery ajax call:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#auto_switch').hide();
        $('#loading').show();
        var broker = '{{ broker }}';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: true,
            url: '{% url 'broker:load_data' %}',
            data: {
                'broker': broker,
            },
            data_type: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#loading').hide()
                $('#auto_switch').show();
                $('#stock_holdings').html(data.rendered_table);
            }
        });
        $("#auto_switch").change(function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                setInterval(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        cache: true,
                        url: '{% url 'broker:load_data' %}',
                        data: {
                            'broker': broker,
                        },
                        data_type: 'html',
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#loading').hide()
                            $('#auto_switch').show();
                            $('#stock_holdings').html(data.rendered_table);
                        }
                    });
                }, 5000);
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: true,
                    url: '{% url 'broker:load_data' %}',
                    data: {
                        'broker': broker,
                    },
                    data_type: 'html',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#loading').hide()
                        $('#auto_switch').show();
                        $('#stock_holdings').html(data.rendered_table);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I am expecting that if **auto-switch** (toggle button is enabled), the function **setInterval** will trigger and the table data will keep refreshing every 5 seconds and on any change in the toggle switch it will find its status as off and no auto refresh will take place. However currently its not auto-refreshing whether the switch is on or off.

Comment: There are better ways to refresh pages than a 5 second setInterval, but I guess this works for a demonstration or simple website.

Comment: ~FSDford Could you please help let me know what other ways other than setInterval could help achieve the task here? Also currently this code is not doing the trick. Irrespective of the toggle switch status, auto refresh of the table data is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :

```
$(document).on('change',"#auto_switch",function(){
```

instead of

```
$("#auto_switch").change(function () {
```

Comment: Tried it but still no change. On toggling the switch to on position, it triggers the url once but doesn't continue doing it every 5 seconds while the switch is still in on position.

Comment: make the following add console.log('its work or not') inside your function before conditions

Comment: then add add console.log('its work after condition') inside your function after conditions

Comment: I mean this condition if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {

Comment: You are right, its not entering the if condition as I see only 'its work or not' on toggle. Need to figure out a way to check the status of the switch now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var shouldRefresh = false;

$(document).on('change', '#auto_switch', function()
{
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    shouldRefresh = isChecked;
    
    if (shouldRefresh)
    {               
        var interval = setInterval(function() 
        {
           if (!shouldRefresh)
                clearInterval(interval);
                
            console.log('This is executed every second');
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```